What exactly is Krishna asking arjuna to abandon in Bhagavad Gita 18.66?
https://www.holy-bhagavad-gita.org/chapter/18/verse/66

सर्वधर्मान्परित्यज्य मामेकं शरणं व्रज |
अहं त्वां सर्वपापेभ्यो मोक्षयिष्यामि मा शुच: || 66||


sarva-dharmān parityajya mām ekaṁ śharaṇaṁ vraja
ahaṁ tvāṁ sarva-pāpebhyo mokṣhayiṣhyāmi mā śhuchaḥ


Abandon all varieties of dharmas and simply surrender unto Me alone. I shall liberate you from all sinful reactions; do not fear.

At another place, he tells Arjuna not to abandon his kshatriya (Varnashrama) Dharma.
Amd since Krishna doesn't appear in the Vedas, he seems to be recommending rejecting the Vedas, too.

sarva Adharma parthiyachha AA is silent

OMG - "atat tvam asi" strikes again.  सर्व | अधर्मान् = सर्वाधर्मान्  There are no silent letters in Sanskrit. @PrasannaR

See whole gita talks doing ones assigned duty, now this one sloka tells you exact opposite.. is it  correct to take literaly say reliqush all duty towards god and surrender no.. According sriman madvacharya reliquish all rewards from the duty towards god and surrender unto lord krishna and vayudeva.

@S K your comment on atat tvam asi makes me  lol.. understand now same simili holds through out the story line swetha ketu was adamant to why he should prostate to his father when he is the topper of the class or gold medalist. now dad himself teachs lesson to his unbecoming son saying that he is god only.. what is context of the story and what is one single sentence.. which is out of context just like sarva dharman prathiyatcha

There are 2 verses in the Gita that talk of surrender. One has to surrender the fruits of karma and sense of agency to God. Surrendering the fruits of karma and sense of agency is an inner attitude of the spiritual aspirant.

Let your mind be engrossed in Me. Be devoted to Me. Offer worship to
Me. Be resigned to Me. Beloved as you are of me, I pledge in troth you
shall come to Me alone.

Gita 18.65

Abandoning dependence on all Dharmas (or on human efforts at moral and
spiritual upliftment), come to Me as the only Refuge. Grieve not; I
will deliver you from all sins.

Gita 18.66

The essence of the Gita teaching is clinched in the verses 18.65 and
18.66. While the Gita teaching has a place for the renunciation of all actions by aspirants who have attained to the purity of mind, its main
thrust is to recommend renunciation not of works but of their fruits
and the sense of agency. In verse 18.66 an aspirant is asked to
abandon all Dharmas. Dharma is interpreted by some schools of thought
as Karmas. If by Karma is meant all Vedic ritualism and ego-centered
work for selfish gains, the equation of Dharma and Karma is all right.
But it cannot be works done as acts of pure devotion and service (see
18.65). So works of the nature of Bhakti discipline should always be performed. These disciplines are in the words of the Bhagavata Purana

Sravanam (hearing about God), Kirtanam (chanting His name and praises), Smaranam (remembering Him through repetition of the Name
etc.), Padasevanam (performing all duties as His service) Arcanam (
worship of Him in images), Vandanam (saluting Him in all beings),
Dasyam ( cultivating the attitude of a servant of His), Sakhyam (
feeling the intimacy of comradeship with Him), and Atmanivedanam
(self-dedication to Him).

Even in the performance of these devotional activities, there is a
form of renunciation to be practiced. There is a tendency among
spiritual aspirants to feel they have done so much Sadhana and nothing
has happened or that they are entitled to the Lord’s grace because
they have done so much of spiritual practices. There is nothing so
stupid and unspiritual as this kind of mentality. The Infinite Being
cannot be purchased for any price of limited commodities. A true
aspirant abandons all the fruits of all his Sadhanas to Him. The
Lord’s grace is bestowed according to His will: man’s duty is only to
pray for it and wait in patience. ….. The surrender of the fruits and
the sense of agency in regard to all one’s spiritual practices even,
besides the abandonment of all non-spiritual activities, is included
in the idea of giving up all Dharma. And with this attitude of mind,
an aspirant must abide in the faith that the Lord is his only support,
his only redeemer, the only determiner of his destiny.
According to Madhusudana Sarasvati, this surrender takes three forms
determined by the maturity of Sadhana.
First, there is that attitude ‘I am His”, the second is the attitude
‘He is mine’, and the third, there is the experience ‘He is I’.
Surrender takes three forms according to one’s spiritual maturity.
In explanation of these, he gives the following example of the first
attitude:
“When the sense of difference subsides, I am, O Lord, Thy appendage,
and not You mine. It is the wave that belongs to the ocean, and never
the ocean to the wave.”
The second stage is represented by the attitude:
“Well Krishna, Thou art forcible snatching Thyself away from me
physically. How strange! I shall only praise Thy valor if Thou art
able to extricate Thyself out of my heart also”. Here the devotee’s
sense of ‘my-ness’ with regard to the Lord is so great that he feels
that He can never separate Himself from him (the devotee).
The third and the highest stage of surrender is represented by the
realization embodied in the verse addressed by Yama to his emissaries
in the Vishnu Purana:
“Do not approach those in whom has arisen the firm conviction that all
that exists is Vasudeva, the one Supreme Lord and Master of all,
dwelling within the heart.” Here the ‘I’ has disappeared in the ‘He’
and there is only He.
One who resorts to Him absolutely, He offers to deliver from all sins.
Sins must be understood in a comprehensive sense, namely the effects
of all karmas, present and past, good and bad, which lead to repeated
births and deaths. Even the effects of good Karma can be called ‘sin’,
as they also lead to repeated births and deaths. In other words the
Lord promises to bestow His grace, and to light in one’s heart the
lamp of wisdom that removes the darkness of Ignorance, which is the
cause of all sin. Individual sins may be absolved by atonements
(prayascitta) but sins or sinful tendency can be effaced only by
Haritosanam - by securing the grace of the Lord.

Commentary on Gita 18.66 by Swami Tapasyananda
